# setManaged=false doesn't work

Tags: java, javafx

I use following code:

```
<VBox fx:id="v" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" managed="false" prefWidth="100" prefHeight="100">
    <Label text="label"/>
</VBox>
```

and the screenshot is:
[image]

the text "label" still exist, how to make VBox disappear and remove its space, If i use Parent#remove, i cannot restore it

Comment: AFAIK, managed=false means the parent doesn't take this node into account when arranging it. If you want to hide the label you should probably set the label's `visible` property to false, as well as it's `managed` property (not the `VBox`'s `managed`).

Answer (score 2):

The `managed` property only determines, whether a `Parent` uses it's own layouting algorithm to determine the position of a child. It does not change the visibility. To remove a child including the occupied space, you need to set the `visible` property to `false` too.

The following example demonstrates this. It "adds/removes" the green rectangle to/from the scene when clicking somewhere on the scene.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, Color.LIME);

    VBox root = new VBox(new Rectangle(100, 100, Color.RED),
                         rect,
                         new Rectangle(100, 100, Color.BLUE));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 300);
    scene.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
        rect.setManaged(!rect.isManaged());
        rect.setVisible(!rect.isVisible());
    });

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

---

Note that a similar effect can also be achieved by adding/removing the node to/form it's parent:

```
scene.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
    if (rect.getParent() == null) {
        root.getChildren().add(1, rect);
    } else {
        root.getChildren().remove(rect);
    }
});
```